# conflict between websocket url and routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, websocket, routes

dear all of master in rails

I am new in developing web app using rails.
Now, i want to try create an app rails using web socket.
I get good tutorial from [here](http://vysakh0.github.io/websockets-in-rails4/)
However, when i improve my experience in rails. I get conflict between url websocket and url created in routes.rb
in my routes.rb

> get ':username' => 'users#profile', as:"profile"

the url get conflict with url web socket and then, my web app websocket getting failure.
anyone could help me to solve my problem..???

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this using a routing constraint:

`get '/:hash', to: 'conversations#show', constraints: {hash: /((?!websocket).)*/}`

The route will not work unless the `:hash` does not contain the string "websocket"

I'm sure there's a better regex out there, and if my hash ever randomly contains the string "websocket" it'll fail.

But, this fixes your problem for me in development.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error exactly?
You need to change the route

```
get '/username' => 'users#profile', as:"profile"
```

I think your should read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

Comment: => get '/username' => 'users#profile', as:"profile"
this route get conflict with
var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('localhost:3000/websocket');